# It gives error after "npm run android" in expo cli

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

i am installing React Native for the first time on this computer. I installed the android studio and react native environment.

I had the this error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5j8W.png

```
Error: adb: failed to install C:\Users\10125651\.expo\android-apk-cache\Exponent-2.25.2.apk: 

Exception occurred while executing 'install':
```

Comment: Did you install expo globally with `npm install -g expo-cli`?

Comment: @server_unknown yes